# What is the same iwlib.h for windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt

This is the scenario

I already have a project in **Linux** using qt, then I was asked to create the same project but in **WINDOWS**. My problem right now is I am using iwlib.h in Linux but then I cannot find a library like ***iwlib.h*** for windows.

Do you know a library that is like iwlib.h for windows

Any suggestions?

Comment: And you might find you don't even need it. And you might find you have to write the functionality yourself. Porting software between targets can be a lot of work. If you find yourself doing it a lot, you'll probably want to invest in an abstraction layer to conceal the differences from your application logic.

Comment: So it means that there's no equivalent iwlib.h for windows?

Comment: @Alyama Instead of focusing on the library you should focus on the functionality since there may not be an equivalent library but there are some of the functionalities.

Comment: Okay, thanks. It is clear now to me that there is no equivalent for this.  I just thought there are equivalent libraries for this like the others. :)